Why aren't other brands of brick products accepted?
There are many alternative brands for LEGO, however, they do not seem to get much attention. On some Web sites, I have observed much hostility cast on these alternative products. Even this Web site uses "LEGO" in the title. I have tried some other brands, and they seem fairly good.

Why is it that these products are not so popular?
Why might people reject an otherwise decent and compatible product?


I may have moved this in haste, when I'm in the office I'll see if I can undo the migration, or just migrate it back, however it is inviting discussion which might make it rather subjective

Try posting about microsoft computers on an apple forum, and you'll find we actually are very tolerant of non-LEGO building bricks.

We do accept other brands of brick toys here on LEGO answers, but we haven't seen many specific questions(mainly because most of the building techniques should be similar).
As Ryan points out, there are certainly compatibility and quality issues with some competitor's products.

The name LEGO carries a sense of quality along with it.
People are reluctant to use other brands, as 99% of the time, they lack the quality and ingenuity that LEGO has.

While it's true for pure "cloning" brands that go so far as to copy LEGO models, including box and instructions (and have atrocious quality), some other brands have reached a level in their own right which is truly noteworthy. Megabloks for example don't copy LEGO models and while I can't speak for their quality (I have none), it's certainly not that bad. The new Kre-O brand from Hasbro will probably fall into that category too. So IMHO 99% may be overrated now.

@Joubarc I actually have owned some Megabloks, I can confirm that the quality is crap compared to LEGO. The blocks just feel cheap in your hand, and the blocks don't lock together nearly as well as LEGO. I have not had any experience with Kre-O, however, I can say that they do not look nearly as cheap-o as Megabloks.
